# swift code error

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var animals  = [Animal]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        self.animals = [Animal(name: "개"),Animal(name: "강아지"),Animal(name: "고양이"),Animal(name: "멍멍이"),Animal(name: "물어")]
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        
        var animal = Animal.self
        
        animal = animals[indexPath.row] //1
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = animal.name //2
        
        return cell //3
    }
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

> error is cannot assign value of type 'Animal' to type 'Animal Type'
>
> error is instance member 'name' cannot be used on type 'Animal
>
> unexpected non-void return value in void function

Comment: `var animal = animals[indexPath.row]` and delete the line above

Comment: If your method has no return type you dont have to return anything

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" is called after you select certain cell, and it does not return anything. Instead, if you want to display the cell, use "cellForRowAtIndexPath".

```
class Animal {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var animals  = [Animal]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.animals = [Animal(name: "개"),Animal(name: "강아지"),Animal(name: "고양이"),Animal(name: "멍멍이"),Animal(name: "물어")]

    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // This would works on your table view
    var animal = animals[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = animal.name 

    return cell 
}

}
```